# How to apply cvsobel + emgucv

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

I am having some problems in using the cvsobel function. I have read that the `cvsobel` increases the image depth from 8 bit to 16bit...

Can somebody help me figure out how i can scale it back to 8 bit ...

My code is

```
Image<Gray, Byte> grayImage = TestImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp(); ;
Image<Gray, Byte> Dest = new Image<Gray, Byte>(grayImage.Size);
Image<Gray, Byte> SobelHorizontal = new Image<Gray, Byte>(grayImage.Size);
CvInvoke.cvCanny(grayImage, Dest, 10, 60, 3);
CvInvoke.cvSobel(Dest, SobelHorizontal, 1, 0, 3); // introduces exception
```

where `TestImage` is a color image I take from the user.

The problem here i think is with the declaration of `SobelHorizontal`... How do i give a 16 bit depth here and make the function work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well EMGU actually has sobel and canny implementations in C#:

```
 //grayImage.Canny(Gray thresh, Gray threshelinking)
 grayImage.Canny(new Gray(10), new Gray(60));
 //grayImage.Sobel(int xorder, intyorder, int aptureSize)
 grayImage.Sobel(1, 0, 3);
```

This Should do as you want without the difficulties you face however as vasile mentioned you can declare the data type of your image however you like

```
Image<Gray,short> Image<Gray,double>, or Image<Gray,float>.
```

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Hey Chris , Thanks a lot ... I am trying to find the horizontal and vertical lines in the image so could you help me out by telling whether using the sobel operators is the right way to go ?

Comment: To be honest Canny is more effective at detecting edges however unlike sobel you can't define which direction to pass. I would suggest using Canny and then using the HoughLines operation to determine which lines are strong vertical and horzontal lines you can chose the angle by playing with variables. The reason being even if you used sobel you then still have to find these lines within the image. If you get stuck feel free to ask and I'll try and answer any question Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Define SobelHoriz as

```
Image<Gray, short>
```

, or whatewer is named the 16 bit integer in C#. Then use the image.convertTo() function to get it back to gray:

```
Image<gray, byte> sobelDisplay;
sobelHoriz.convertTo(sobelDisplay);
```

I do not know how you call it in C#. In c++, the image object has a convertTo() member

Comment: does'nt work because i need to know the size of SobelHoriz for initialisation ...

Comment: All you have to do is to change Byte to short in your definition of sobelHorizontal. And make sure you know the basics of C# programming before trying such a challenging project.

Comment: `Image<Gray, short> = new Image<Gray , short> ( grayImage.Size )` gives me the same error on sobel ...... However Chris 's solution has helped me out ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can set it directly too.

**Example:**

```
Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte> objImagemTemplate = new Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>(objBitmapTemplate); // Image A
objImagemTemplate = (objImagemTemplate.Canny(new Gray(10), new Gray(60)).Sobel(1, 0, 1)).Convert<Gray, Byte>();
```